# limiting the number of images you can upload

Tags: fine-uploader

UPDATED QUESTION

OK new idea.
.on('deleteComplete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {

}
how can I call the sessionRequestComplete function.  I think this might "refresh" the array and solve this issue.

Matt

---

I am trying to limit the number of images a person can upload.
I also need to include the ability to have the orginal file plus two scaled images.

When I tired to use the

validation: {
      itemLimit:6
  }

option I needed to triple the number of items since I was have the system upload three images.

I got this all to work but the issue I am having is if I delete an image and then add a new image and to this a couple of times, the system will then alert me that I have exceeded the itemlimit.

is there a way to "refresh" the items in the current session of the uploader in the deleteComplete function.

thanks.
Matt

Comment: In what context are you doing these things?

Comment: on an image upload page.
we have a tool that the person can upload 2 images.
we need three image sizes so we use the scaling option.

The itemLimit works fine, but the issue is if you upload an image and then you delete and then try to upload again - doing this muliple times you sometimes get a message stating you have reached the itemlimit that is set.

The question I have is can you call a function that will refresh the   uploader object to have the current number of images that you have active in your uploading session

Answer (score 0):

The itemLimit validation rule is quite literal.  You'll need to keep this in mind when you determine a proper number. if you are using it with scaled image generation turned on.

If you are looking to adjust this value dynamically, or expect it to work differently, please open up a feature request.